# Horizontal Navigation Size Issues

Tags: css

I am trying to create a horizontal navigation similar to link [1], but it's looking like link [2].How can I code it the way I want it to look? The width of the wrapper is 80em. Each link is 155x76px. Every time I covert that number to em, it's giving me a smaller size. I still have to get use to calculating in em.

Thanks!

[1] http://vivianaa.siteground.net/Beatles/layout.png
[2] http://vivianaa.siteground.net/Beatles/html.png

```
.menuarea {
   border: 0.08em solid #080;
   background-color: #81898e;
   }

.menulist{
    text-align:center;    
    } 

 .menulist li{
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:center;
    padding: 1em 2em;
    background-color:#d9b607;
    margin: 0 1.100em;
    }

 .menulist li:hover {background-color:black;}   

 .menulist li a:active {color:#d9b607;}

 .menulist li:active {background-color:81898e;}


<nav class="menuarea">

                <ul class="menulist">
                    <li>
                        <a href="index(2).html">the beatles</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="john.html">john</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="paul.html">paul</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="george.html">george</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="ringo.html">ringo</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're em under ".menulist li" is too high.  If you want something that looks like link 1, use this:

```
margin: 0.1em;
```

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/prPnF/)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for helping me out. I tried your code, but I think my measurements were off that it collapsed everything to the next line. I ended up changing to navigation.